# Requests not defined after importing from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have imported a file `image_function.py` to my notebook. However when i tried using one of the functions `im_reverse`, it gave me an error.

Code:

```
import image_function
image_function.im_reverse("https://allhdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/sunset-8.jpg", reverse = 'horizontal', url = True)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-afc744ac8a12> in <module>()
      1 import image_function
----> 2 image_function.im_reverse("https://allhdwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/sunset-8.jpg", reverse = 'horizontal', url = True)

/content/image_function.py in im_reverse(image_path, reverse, url)
     45           mat_image_column_reverse[c][i] = mat_image_reverse[j][i]
     46           c += 1
---> 47 
     48       plt.axis('off')
     49 
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
```

The error happened before it reached the code for reversing vertically, which is down below.

What's inside image_function:

```
#libraries:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
from PIL import Image
import copy
import requests
from io import BytesIO
```

This is the code after the error:

```
def im_reverse(image_path, reverse = 'horizontal', url = True):
  if url == True:
    response = requests.get(image_path)
    with Image.open(BytesIO(response.content)) as image:
      mat_image = np.array(image, dtype=int)
      m, n, depth = mat_image.shape

    if reverse == 'horizontal':
      mat_image_reverse = copy.deepcopy(mat_image)
      mat_image_rows_reverse = copy.deepcopy(mat_image)
      
      for i in range(m):
        c = 0
        for j in range(n-1,-1,-1):
          mat_image_rows_reverse[i][c] = mat_image_reverse[i][j]
          c += 1
      
      plt.axis('off')
      return imshow(mat_image_rows_reverse)
```

I have tried a lot of solutions on the web. However i dont see anything wrong. I have also tried a deliberate `from requests import get` or `!pip install requests` and it still didn't work.

Can anyone please offer a solution. Thanks

Comment: Can we see the line on which this error occurs?

Comment: Please update the question to include the full error traceback message, not just the final error line.

Comment: Sir @JohnGordon,  i have edited it

Comment: That is a strange traceback message .. the arrow points to line 47 which is empty.  Can you check to see if you have an old version of `image_function.pyc` in that directory, and if so, remove it?

Comment: oh yeah, thanks, i do have an old version of it. It works now

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to install requests:

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

Comment: If this were the cause then it would be an `ImportError`, not a `NameError`.